# How does linq actually execute the code to retrieve data from the data source?

Tags: c#, linq

I will start working on xamarin shortly and will be transferring a lot of code from android studio's java to c#.

In java I am using a custom classes which are given arguments conditions etc, convert them to SQL statements and then loads the results to the objects in the project's model

What I am unsure of is wether linq is a better option for filtering such data.

For example what would happen currently is somethng along these lines

```
List<Customer> customers = (new CustomerDAO()).get_all()
```

Or if I have a condition

```
List<Customer> customers = (new CustomerDAO()).get(new Condition(CustomerDAO.Code, equals, "code1")
```

Now let us assume I have transferred the classes to c# and I wish to do somethng similar to the second case.

So I will probably write something along the lines of:

```
var customers = from customer 
    in (new CustomerDAO()).get_all() 
    where customer.code.equals("code1")
    select customer
```

I know that the query will only be executed when I actually try to access customers, but if I have multiple accesses to customers ( let us say that I use 4 foreach loops later on) will the get_all method be called 4 times? or are the results stored at the first execution?

Also is it more efficient (time wise because memory wise it is probably not) to just keep the get_all() method and use linq to filter the results? Or use my existing setup which in effect executes

```
Select * from Customers where code = 'code1'
```

And loads the results to an object?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Edit: yes I do know there is sqlite.net which pretty much does what my daos do but probably better, and at some point I will probably convert all my objects to use it, I just need to know for the sake of knowing

Comment: Which LINQ are you referring to? LINQ to objects? LINQ to EF? LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Yes, the dao creates List<T>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I have multiple accesses to customers ( let
>   us say that I use 4 foreach loops later on) will the get_all method be
>   called 4 times? or are the results stored at the first execution?

Each time you enumerate the enumerator (using `foreach` in your example), the query will re-execute, unless you store the materialized result somewhere. For example, if on the first query you'd do:

```
var customerSource = new CustomerDAO();
List<Customer> customerSource.Where(customer => customer.Code.Equals("code1")).ToList();
```

Then now you'll be working with an in-memory `List<Customer>` without executing the query over again.

On the contrary, if each time you'd do:

```
var filteredCustomers = customerSource.Where(customer => customer.Code.Equals("code1"))
foreach (var customer in filteredCustomers)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Then for each enumeration you'll be exeucting the said query over again.

> Also is it more efficient (time wise because memory wise it is
>   probably not) to just keep the get_all() method and use linq to filter
>   the results? Or use my existing setup which in effect executes

That really depends on your use-case. Lets imagine you were using LINQ to EF, and the customer table has a million rows, do you really want to be bringing all of them in-memory and only then filtering them out to use a subset of data? It would usually be better to full filtered query.

Comment: So it is either do the proccess once before ever needing the results, or performing it each time I need them, guess I have to choose between performance over memory usage, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Cruces It is not as easy and simple - unless you are ignorant to what databases do. If you have 64 million customers and see kby name and the table in the server has an index on name, it may well be ALSO faster to ask the database server than running along an array. Implementing your own in memory database is a very different beast from just having LINQ to Objects run over an in memory collection. The tradeoff is thus not as trivial as you make it. On top, what about updates to said customers? How do you reload them? ;)

Comment: Nah I'm not working with that big databases, most tables don't have more than 400k entries, but I see your point, I usually page data when there are too many rows.I was just wandering what the effect would be when I have to search through something whose size I know (for example my post codes table has about 100 entries and will probably never reach more than 200). I usually work with prototypes of such data, I was just wandering if it would be better to load them on the spot, because even the prototype pattern has some problems.

Comment: As for updates and alterations, I work on mobile applications, so most of the time I don't have to worry about someone altering data from my database. I have a syncinc process with the central database, and only work with local ones